# Convert nested list to 2d array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

I'm trying to convert a nested list into a 2d array.

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
list.add(Arrays.asList("dd"));
list.add(Arrays.asList("eee", "fff"));
```

I want to make this a `String[][]`. I've tried the following:

```
String[][] array = (String[][]) list.toArray();      // ClassCastException

String[][] array = list.toArray(new String[3][3]);   // ArrayStoreException

String[][] array = (String[][]) list.stream()        // ClassCastException
    .map(sublist -> (String[]) sublist.toArray()).toArray();
```

Is there a way that works? Note that I won't know the size of the list until runtime, and it may be jagged.

Comment: You haven't tried to do it manually with two nested `for` loops?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no simple builtin way to do what you want because your `list.toArray()` can return only array of elements stored in list which in your case would also be lists.

Simplest solution would be creating two dimensional array and filling it with results of `toArray` from each of nested lists.

```
String[][] array = new String[list.size()][];

int i = 0;
for (List<String> nestedList : list) {
    array[i++] = nestedList.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

(you can shorten this code if you are using Java 8 with streams just like [Alex did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26726451/1393766))

Answer (score 36):

You could do this:

```
String[][] array = list.stream()
    .map(l -> l.stream().toArray(String[]::new))
    .toArray(String[][]::new);
```

It creates a `Stream<List<String>>` from your list of lists, then from that uses [`map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) to replace each of the lists with an array of strings which results in a `Stream<String[]>`, then finally calls [`toArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray-java.util.function.IntFunction-)(with a generator function, instead of the no-parameter version) on that to produce the `String[][]`.

Comment: How about primitive types like "double[][]" ?

Comment: @fuat `list.stream()
    .map(l -> l.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray())
    .toArray(double[][]::new)` if list is a `List<List<Double>>`. It will throw a NullPointerException if any of the Doubles are null though.

Comment: i use this `.stream().map(p -> new double[] {p.get(0), p.get(1)}).toArray(double[][]::new)` but your solution looks better. thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the best and most efficient way to convert 2d list to 2d array;

```
List<List<Integer>>  list2d = new ArrayList<>();
Integer[][] array2d;

array2d = list2d.stream().map(x->x.toArray(new Integer[x.size()])).toArray(Integer[][]::new);
```