# List<List<String>> to String[][]

Tags: java, arrays

Is there any shortcut in java to convert

```
List<List<String>>
```

to

```
String[][]
```

? toArray does not work:

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(Collections.singletonList("test"));
String[][] array = list.toArray(new String[0][]);
System.out.println(array);

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException
    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3213)
    at java.util.ArrayList.toArray(ArrayList.java:407)
    at main(Api.java:1001)
```

this is not an Duplicate of [Convert nested list to 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26726366/convert-nested-list-to-2d-array) because i'm looking for a shortcut/lib, not an basic implemantation

Comment: You could write it yourself, shouldn't be too hard. Besides that I bet theres a utility in Guava or Apache Commons.

Comment: could you post the guava version as answer?

Comment: no i'm lloking for a shortcut, not an custom implemantation

Comment: Do you really have a need for that? When I see a collection of collection (or array of array), I start implementing a new intermediate class e.g. `Row`. It would make the code clearer. The question would be "How to map a `List<Row>` into a `Row[]`" and the answer would be obvious.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Agreed.  Certainly better than looking at ugly List<List<String>>.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some Java 8 lambda to do so:

```
// original List<List<String>>
List<List<String>> nestedList = new ArrayList<>();
// adding test values
nestedList.add(new ArrayList<String>(){{add("a");add("b");}});
nestedList.add(new ArrayList<String>(){{add("c");add("c");}});
nestedList.add(new ArrayList<String>(){{add("e");add("f");}});
// printing the original List<List<String>>
System.out.println(nestedList);
String[][] nestedArray = nestedList
    // using the stream API
    .stream()
    // mapping each `List`...
    .map(
        // ... to a resulting array
        (l) -> l.toArray(new String[l.size()])
    )
    // collecting as a List<String[]>
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
    // converting the resulting List<String[]> to a String[][]
    .toArray(new String[nestedList.size()][]);
// printing the resulting 2-dimensional array
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(nestedArray));
```

**Output**

```
[[a, b], [c, c], [e, f]]
[[a, b], [c, c], [e, f]]
```

Comment: shorter variant: String[][] result = lst.stream().map(list -> list.toArray(new String[list.size()])).toArray(String[][]::new);